# How to make buttons modify data from database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have a page which connects to the database and gets some data including title and content.
 I use a while loop to echo the data inside this page, what I'm trying to do is to have 2 buttons under every result that comes from database which is the "Edit" and "Delete" buttons. The problem is I don't know how to make buttons remove or edit the right column.
**EDIT**
Added the PHP part:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <section>
        <b>Title: </b>
        <p><?php echo $row['name'] ?></p><br>
        <b>Content: </b><br>
        <p><?php echo $row['content'] ?></p><br>
//want to have two buttons here which can be used to edit or delete the colunm that they are under it
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Please post your actual code i.e. HTML and PHP code, CSS is of no use here.

Comment: what are you trying to edit or delete? the content within the div, the title, both?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul added the php

Comment: @DCR Edit and delete both

Comment: @Potatoman, Though the solution is pretty broad and subjective, I have given an answer below to get you started on this. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an *id* column in *posts* table i.e. you have a unique id value associated with each row, create a `<form>...</form>` block encapsulating both *Edit* and *Delete* buttons, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC $limit";
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <section>
        <b>Title: </b>
        <p><?php echo $row['name'] ?></p><br />
        <b>Content: </b><br>
        <p><?php echo $row['content'] ?></p><br />
        <form action="YOURPAGE.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Edit" />&nbsp;
            <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
        </form>
    </section>
    <?php
}
```

So once you hit *Edit* or *Delete* button of a particular row, the form will get submitted and you will be able get that particular row id using `$_GET['id']` on *YOURPAGE.php* page. Based on that row id, perform the edit or delete operation accordingly.

**YOURPAGE.php**

```
<?php
    /* get row id */
    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;

    if(isset($id) && isset($_POST['edit'])){
        /* Edit button has been clicked */

        /* create a prepared statement */
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT name, content FROM posts WHERE id = ?")
        if($stmt){
            /* bind parameters */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $id);

            /* execute query */
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            /* bind result variables */
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $name, $content);

            /* fetch value */
            mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

            /* close statement */
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

            ?>
            <form action="" method="post">
                <b>Title: </b><input type="text" name="title" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /><br />
                <b>Content: </b><br />
                <textarea name="content" ><?php echo $content; ?></textarea><br />
                <input type="submit" name="editrow" value="Edit" />
            </form>
            <?php
        }else{
            /* error */
        }
    }

    if(isset($id) && isset($_POST['editrow'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = $_POST['content'];

        /* edit row details based on the row id i.e. $id */
    }

    if(isset($id) && isset($_POST['delete'])){
        /* Delete button has been clicked */
        /* Delete row based on the row id i.e. $id */
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried to use this and I fixed it with my code but when I click on edit or delete nothing appears on _YOURPAGE.PHP_ which is because `if(isset($id) && isset($_POST['edit']))` fails, and also the URL for the page looks like this which doesn't seem to be right : _YOURPAGE.PHP?delete=Delete_ and _YOURPAGE.PHP?edit=Edit_

Comment: @Potatoman, I have changed the first form's method from `get` to `post`, [https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55785404/3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/55785404/3), now it should work, please check with the updated solution.